# Snakemake with hierarchical yaml configs

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a snakemake pipeline and different config files for different runs.
The parameters of these runs however overlap, so I would like to **create one default.yaml file that the specific run configs *inherit* from**, so I only have to change some key parameters in each run config.

I am thinking of a directory structure like this:

```
config/
    default.yaml
    run_configs/
        run_A.yaml
        run_B.yaml
```

However, I don't know how to make the yaml files inherit from the "default.yaml" file.

I should note that I specify my configfile **at runtime**, i.e. I don't want to hardcode the configs in the Snakefile.

Answer (score 0):

The order of `configfile` directives will matter. Specifically, the last one will overwrite the overlapping keys of the previous configurations.

For your use case this means that first the default yaml will need to be loaded, and then the one that you would like to use for the specific run.

For example:

```py
configfile: "default.yaml"
configfile: "run_configs/run_A.yaml"
```

Here, the `config` object will contain all the configurations in "default.yaml" and if there are any configurations in "run_A.yaml" that have the same keys, then the final values will be the ones from "run_A.yaml".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I should clarify that I define the configfile at runtime, I dont want to hardcode it in the Snakefile. Will update my question.